# gRPC java call takes much longer than deadline

Tags: grpc-java

My java gRPC Blocking unary client has a deadline 200ms, set in service config. In most of the cases when server takes longer than timeout to respond, it failed with `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` exception and call takes very close to 200ms but under load (30-40 requests per sec) actual call time goes up to 2 sec. I do not see a significant GC pauses in the logs.

Error logs:

DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after -0.842086528s. [closed=[], open=[[remote_addr=<..>]]]

DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after -0.405366113s. [closed=[], open=[[wait_for_ready, buffered_nanos=285874, waiting_for_connection]]]

I switched to FutureStub and using `ListenableFuture.get` with the same 200 ms but that did not help.
The `TimeoutException` from `ListenableFuture.get` have message `Waited 200 milliseconds (plus 74930 nanoseconds delay)` with `status=PENDING`
Any suggestions how to enforce client side timeout to be "on time" ?

Answer (score 0):

gRPC uses an `EventLoopGroup` (an executor service) to execute the deadline timer callbacks. If you are using the default [`DEFAULT_EVENT_LOOP_GROUP_POOL`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/netty/src/main/java/io/grpc/netty/NettyChannelBuilder.java#L86) then at heavy load it is probably not able to execute the callbacks on time. You may consider using a custom executor using [`NettyChannelBuilder.eventLoopGroup()`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/netty/src/main/java/io/grpc/netty/NettyChannelBuilder.java#L327). One example is here https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/alts/src/main/java/io/grpc/alts/HandshakerServiceChannel.java#L62